# 4K 250 frames Architectural animation Is it possible to render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Hi I got an architectural indoor scene that I want to render 250 frames in 4K. I got the samples down to 300 with the denoiser. ( Cycles, blender 2.90 ). I tried to upload the animation to a render farm but ended up paying 200+ USD since my computer isn't good enough. If I had a Ryzen thread ripper and a rtf 3080, would I be able to render the animation sequence without a render farm and about how long would it take? Understand all scenes are different depending on allot of reasons but for a quite heavy interior scene. Unfortunately I can't share images since I signed a NDA.

Comment: Other than memory constraints (read a scene is too complex to fit into available memory), every scene should be renderable in all supported hardware. Whether it will take an acceptable amount of time or not depends on a lot of factors, like how long you deem is an acceptable amount of time to wait, how fast the hardware is, how complex the scene is, how long you are able to wait, non of which we can really assess here.

Comment: Hello :). Just to get you in a ballpark. [In this BlenderGuru's video](https://youtu.be/iFQokXmqmVQ?t=888) he renders 250 frames, 4K, 300 samples = 62 hours rendertime on his Dual Titan RTX.

Comment: @JachymMichal thank you for replying

Comment: If you aren't using the features that are currently missing (volumes and maybe some other things) you could try the experimental Cycles X build.  Cycles X is a massive performance increase, but it is currently incomplete.

Comment: Render farms inform you what hardware rendered your project and how much time it took. Compare that with hardware of your choice to roughly estimate how much time it would take for you. Then calculate electricity usage while rendering, multiply by the time, and together with other pros (e.g. having a better GPU for faster previews, games etc.) and cons (e.g. having the PC unavailable while rendering) decide which option is better.

Comment: Also, if you render on a render farm, you do technically share your images, but of course there's a significant difference of doing that and posting the images on public forums.